# Merge [monitor] into [display]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, tag-synonyms

I have been looking at tags to clean up, and I came across the tags [displays](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/displays) (6 questions) and [monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) (8 questions). Most of the questions are asking for the same hardware. One monitor question is actually about [baby monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/179/60).

When I hear "monitor", the first thing that comes to mind is a computer monitor, which isn't the only type of display. Therefor I am proposing that we merge monitors into displays, as a monitor is a type of display.

Comment: If merging doesn't make sense, suggest in an answer what else we could do. IMO, the tags are too similar to co-exist as is.

Comment: Once again I will look at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/tags/display/synonyms) to see what they have done. I realize that we also deal with other types of displays, so what they have done won't 100% work here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways I can see this working out.

*Display* is essentially a synonym for *screen*, and a *monitor* is a type of *screen*, so *monitor* is already just a subset of *display*. So should we get rid of [monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor)? I say no. A monitor is a specific piece of hardware used to see and interact with a computer. This makes it an essential tag to the site. [display](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) covers a much wider range of *screens* that could be on anything from a computer's fan controller to a smartwatch — I wouldn't necessarily call these monitors.

So to merge [monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) → [display](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display), you would have to argue that monitors themselves aren't a major piece of hardware this site focuses on.

If you wanted to merge [display](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/display) → [monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor), you would have to argue that a monitor is absolutely any type of screen on any kind of hardware. This is a big stretch in my opinion.

I think we should keep them as is because they both refer to certain things. However, if we do this, we need to work on cleaning them up and clarifying their meanings because we wouldn't be here if they were already like that.

---

**Edit**
Based on the definitions I gave for each tag above (in the first paragraph), I have come up with simpler definitions:

[monitors](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors) — any standalone screen that isn't physically a part of another component. The obvious example is a computer monitor you connect to a computer.

[displays](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/displays) — any screen integrated into a device. Good examples are [kiosk screens](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/421/155) and [e-reader screens](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/522/155).

Comment: After I posted my question, this is how I felt about them. There are a few questions that use [display] when they should use [monitor] and that is a problem that I am not sure how to fix. I really don't want to go through all questions with the display tag to make sure that they should have used [monitor] instead every few months.